# Batch rename directories in reverse order

Tags: python, linux, bash, sed

I have a bunch (more than 700) directories that are named in the following manner

```
1 - *random*name*1*
2 - *random*name*2*
...
725 - *random*name*725*
```

The leading numbers (1-725) are all part of the directory names.

**That is: all directory names start with  a number, followed by [space][dash][space], followed by some text.**

I'd like to batch rename them, so that they'll be named as following:

```
1 - *random*name*725*
2 - *random*name*724*
...
725 - *random*name*1*
```

I'd like to "reverse" just the number parts of the directory names. Essentially I'd like the text that came after "1 - " to follow "725 - ", the text that came after "2 - " to follow "724 - " and so on.

What is the easiest way to do that? I'm on linux.

**Note:** The *random*names* are all different and are just for illustration purposes.

Comment: Does "random name" stand for the *same* name for all 725 directories, or different names?

Comment: What have you tried?  I'd start with looking at the `os` and `copy` modules in conjunction with the `reverse()` method of lists.

Comment: hm, I usually do this stuff in the ipython shell. Using `import glob, re, shutil`. So I don't really write a script, just get all the filenames (glob), create a regex that does what I want, loop over filenames and transform them, and when that all works, add the actual rename command to the loop

Comment: Are all the random names distinct? Otherwise, you're liable to get collision problems ex. when `*foo*1*` and `*foo*725*` both initially exist.

Comment: And if the list of input names is `abc1`, `def2`, `ghi3`, is the desired result `abc3`, `def2`, `ghi3`, or is it `ghi3`, `def2`, `abc1`?  This question is rather unclear.

Comment: What does the `*` following the number represent? Is the number always the last part of the name, or is the number embedded somewhere in the middle?

Comment: I clarified the problem a bit. All filenames start with a number. I'd like to "reverse" those numbers. 

Bear in mind, I'm a newbie in python. I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Are you looking to use python or bash? Easiest way totally depends on the language of your choice.

Comment: are the `*` characters literally '*' or do they match anything?  (this is especially important for the one at the end of each filename).

Comment: @Samveen It doesn't really matter to me. It's a one time thing. I'd sooner use bash, but if it's much easier to do this in python, that's fine with me.

Comment: @mgilson everything that comes after "## - " is just some text.

Comment: @zigamilek -- Sorry, I don't follow.  I see no `##-` in your question.

Comment: @mgilson `## -` as in `number - `. All directory names start with a number, followed by [space][dash][space], followed by some text.

Comment: Couldn't you just strip the number at the end and append 726-[number you're on]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `perl`. Code is commented.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename qw|basename|;

die qq{Usage: perl $0 <real|trial>\n} unless @ARGV == 1;

my $real = $ARGV[0] eq q|real| ? 1 : 0;

## Filter filenames from the directory that match criteria of OP.
my @files = grep { -d $_ && m/\A(\d+)\s-\s.*\1/ } map { basename $_ } <./*>;

## Get numbers in reverse mode to substitute them later in filenames .
my @nums = map { m/\A(\d+)/; $1 || 0 } reverse @files;

## Process all files, change the number of the file and rename it.
for my $file ( @files ) { 
    (my $new_file = $file) =~ s/\A(\d+)/shift @nums/e;

    if ( $real ) { 
        rename $file, $new_file or warn qq|WARN: Couldn't rename "$file"\n|;
    }   
    else {
        printf qq|%s\n|, qq|rename "$file" "$new_file"|;
    }   
}
```

List directory:

```
ls -1
```

With following output:

```
1 - file1file
2 - fi2le
3 - fileeee3
4 - fou4r
5 -  donttouch
6 -  donttouch5either
script.pl
```

Run the script:

```
perl script.pl
```

list the directoy again:

```
ls -1
```

With following output:

```
1 - fou4r
2 - fileeee3
3 - fi2le
4 - file1file
5 -  donttouch
6 -  donttouch5either
script.pl
```

---

**EDIT**: There was a suggestion in comments to let a trial run before the real one, so I added an argument `real` or `trial`. With first option it will do real changes, while with second one it will `print` to output the real command but without running them. Now run the script like:

```
perl script.pl real
```

or

```
perl script.pl trial
```

Comment: Thanks, we're getting somewhere. I think you went to more complications than needed. Note that all directory names start with a number, followed by [space][dash][space], followed by some text **that I don't want modified** (even if it contains numbers). The result I'd like to see from your example is `1 - fou4r, 2 - fileeee3, 3 - fi2le, 4 - file1file`. I'm sorry, perl is just like gibberish to me, so I can't modify your code by myself.

Comment: Thank you! I've tested in on test directories and it works. Is there any way to first do a "trial run" on the actual directories without making any changes? As you would "echo mv" in console before actually doing "mv"?

Comment: @zigamilek: Edited my answer to let that option too.

Comment: Thanks. But I think something is missing. Trial run doesn't print aynthing, real run doesn't rename aynthing.

Comment: @zigamilek: The script works for me as before. Are you sure you are running it with same specifications of your question? It doesn't print anything because it doesn't find any directory with your details. Check it again, please.

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is. The text after `1 - `  **doesn't necessarily include `1`** It's just some random text. The leading number doesn't get repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first simulate some filenames:

```
$ printf 'kjdfh8\nskdjfh9\nckjhv10\naskjdh11\n'
kjdfh8
skdjfh9
ckjhv10
askjdh11
```

Then run 'em through a pipe:

```
$ printf 'kjdfh8\nskdjfh9\nckjhv10\naskjdh11\n' | sed 's/[^0-9]*\(.*\)/\1 &/' | sort -nr | cut -d\  -f2-
askjdh11
ckjhv10
skdjfh9
kjdfh8
```

How does this work?  It's actually really simple.  First, we use `sed` to put a copy of any numeric content at the beginning of the line.  Next, we sort.  Finally, we use `cut` to strip off the number at the beginning of the line.  And voilà!

Now... That just reverses the order.  That's one of the questions in your question, but your end goal is to rename things.  We can extend the list above with another pipe that is also a while loop.  This time I'll space things out for easier reading.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
printf 'kjdfh8\nskdjfh9\nckjhv10\naskjdh11\n' \
| sed 's/[^0-9]*\(.*\)/\1 &/' | sort -nr | cut -d\  -f2- \
| while read file; do
    base="${file/[0-9]*/}"
    ((n++))
    printf 'mv "%s" "%s%s"\n' "$file" "$base" "$n"
  done
```

This while loop reads in the list of files we created above.  It gets the "base" by removing everything in the filename starting with the first digit.  It increments a counter (used for the new name), then prints a `mv` command with the old filename, base and counter.

Again, the output of this script is a set of `mv` commands which you can pipe through a shell.

Obviously, to use this on your files, you will need to replace the initial `printf` command with something that generates a list of your files.

**NOTE**: It is usually inadvisable to process filenames in this way, due to the risk of unexpected or special characters (even spaces) turning up in filenames and throwing off your plans.  Only do this if you're confident that you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

if this awk solution ok for you?

cmd:

```
ls -F|grep "/$"|sort|awk 'BEGIN{FS=" - ";l=5;}{o=$0;gsub("/$","",o);gsub($1"/$",l--);if(o!=$0)printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n",o,$0 }' |sh
```

here the 5 is hard coded, in your case would be 725. :) of course it could be set by wc -l, but I am abit lazy.

test:

```
kent$  tree -d
.
|-- 1 - foo1
|-- 2 - foo2
|-- 3 - foo3
|-- 4 - foo4
`-- 5 - foo5

5 directories

#this will only print the generated mv command:

kent$  ls -F|grep "/$"|sort|awk 'BEGIN{FS=" - ";l=5;}{o=$0;gsub("/$","",o);gsub($1"/$",l--);if(o!=$0)printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n",o,$0 }'   
mv "1 - foo1" "1 - foo5"
mv "2 - foo2" "2 - foo4"
mv "4 - foo4" "4 - foo2"
mv "5 - foo5" "5 - foo1"

# if you pipe the generated command to "sh", they will be executed:

kent$  ls -F|grep "/$"|sort|awk 'BEGIN{FS=" - ";l=5;}{o=$0;gsub("/$","",o);gsub($1"/$",l--);if(o!=$0)printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n",o,$0 }' |sh


#result:

kent$  tree -d
.
|-- 1 - foo5
|-- 2 - foo4
|-- 3 - foo3
|-- 4 - foo2
`-- 5 - foo1

5 directories
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately it doesn't work as I'd like it to. Note that all directory names start with a number, followed by [space][dash][space], followed by some text. That text is different every time and doesn't necessarily contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
find /path/to/the/directories/location/ -depth -exec mv '{}' $(basename '{}')$(echo $(date "+%H%M%S%N")) \;
```