# Recursively rename directory in reverse order, Bash script

Tags: bash, centos6

How do I recursively rename a directory structure? Something like [Batch rename directories in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561479/batch-rename-directories-in-reverse-order)

But a simple one liner??

My attempt to do this went futile, Here is the command I tried anyway.

```
du . | cut -f 2- | sh -c 'mv "$0" echo `date "+%H%M%S%N"` ' {} \;
```

Using CentOS 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use `find -exec` syntax without actually using `find`. Use `find` with its `-depth` option to make it return directories from deepest to closest.

```
find . -depth -type d ! -name '.' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$0.$(date "+%H%M%S%N")"' {} \;
```

Comment: That worked! Any way to avoid trying to avoid . from rename operation?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
find /path/to/the/directories/location/ -depth -exec mv '{}' $(basename '{}')$(echo $(date "+%H%M%S%N")) \;
```